# URL generates a 302 redirect when clicking it in a link for most browsers - but returns 200 when typing it

Tags: redirect, request, response, status

I am setting up a small website on Joomla and came across a weird redirect problem.

I wanted to include a link in my website to a Forum that is set up in a different server.

When I type or copy/paste the forum url in the browser, it works perfectly: http://www.techcomputerworld.com/almeriarocketry/

This is the request/response:

```
Request URL:http://www.techcomputerworld.com/almeriarocketry/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:phpbb3_gu83i_u=1; phpbb3_gu83i_k=; phpbb3_gu83i_sid=5d7245ace142f186e3049d7666c528d7; __utma=214190226.1703438907.1378288831.1378288831.1378288831.1; __utmb=214190226.1.10.1378288831; __utmc=214190226; __utmz=214190226.1378288831.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); style_cookie=null
Host:www.techcomputerworld.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36

Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private, no-cache="set-cookie"
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:3805
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 04 Sep 2013 10:05:56 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=29
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

So I happily inserted a link in my website to that URL. But when I click it, the server throws a 302 redirect to another, completely different location:

```
Request URL:http://www.techcomputerworld.com/almeriarocketry/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=214190226.1703438907.1378288831.1378288831.1378288831.1; __utmc=214190226; __utmz=214190226.1378288831.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); phpbb3_gu83i_u=1; phpbb3_gu83i_k=; phpbb3_gu83i_sid=a6f51f7f13a419b2ba46137a8cd6fc3b; style_cookie=null
Host:www.techcomputerworld.com
Referer:http://clubaereotabernas.net/index.php/el-club/instalaciones
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:313
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Wed, 04 Sep 2013 17:56:33 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=30
Location:http://schiedsrichterge.bplaced.net/acwf.html?h=719406
Server:Apache
```

The only different that I can see is the referrer header, but I tried to simulate exactly the same values on my REST client and the call returned a 200.

I am experiencing this in Safari, Firefox, Chrome. It doesn't redirect when using IE8.

Any help, much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 302 means moved temporarily and should supply a new redirection URL for clients to use. Its not dangerous, just annoying to your logs. The key here is the `Location:http://schiedsrichterge.bplaced.net/acwf.html?h=719406` line

Comment: But I don't get why I don't get the 302 when hitting the URL directly? 

It's actually a problem because the URL where I get redirected doesn't exist and fails.

Comment: This most likely has to do with your server configuration. Try ServerFault.com and supply more info about your server.

Comment: Created another post on serverfault.com: http://serverfault.com/questions/537729/url-generates-a-302-redirect-when-clicking-it-in-a-link-for-most-browsers-but/537941?iemail=1&noredirect=1#537941